# how to display results from database in same page in html

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am currently new to php.I am trying to display results from a database to the same html page.However am not using a form for searching,the search is universal.How can i display the results in same page?

For example heres a part of my html page

```
 <body>
    <div class="div1>
<a href="">button to display results</a>
</div>
<div class="div2">
</div>
```

and in my php everything is working fine.However i want when a user clicks the "button to display results" link,the results from the database should be displayed in div2.Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to do this yet?  Can you print anything out with php at all?

Comment: yes the php script is ok.but i dont know,should i refference it in the button link above?

Comment: There are a few different ways to approach this.  Javascript with a hidden container, or AJAX to pull that data and populate it into the page.  Have you tried to implement using either approach?

Comment: Inside of `.div2` why don't you just have `if (button submitted) { display results }`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it will cause the page to refresh passing 1 to the query string to indicate whether to display or not

```
<div class="div1>
      <a href="/?display=1">button to display results</a>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <?php
         $display = $_GET['display'];

         if($display)
         {
             //do some dispaly here
         }
      ?>

</div>
```